# Script to define background on load, with width/height variable

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I need a script (javascript) to define the body background onload,
because first I have a script to see which is the widht and height of the page. Then, it gives me two variables ("W" and "H").
I want that the background has the width=W and height=H.
So probably, the best solution is to run some script that after get the width and height of page, puts a background on the body.

```
<script>
function fundo() {
var w = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;

var h = window.innerHeight
|| document.documentElement.clientHeight
|| document.body.clientHeight;

}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="fundo()" style="background: 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiu8PAY4rJ4WNg2MqwpMfBQ5w3jAXxu5JMYhgImhog9quU-ikZWq8AgQ'; width: "+ w +" height: "+ h +";" >
</body>
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Did you try window.onload and it didn't work out for you?

Comment: Added my code to first post @AlexeySoshin

Comment: Not able to understand your problem. Do you have the working code somewhere to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some specific reasons not to do it in CSS, you should do it like that:

```js
var url = "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiu8PAY4rJ4WNg2MqwpMfBQ5w3jAXxu5JMYhgImhog9quU-ikZWq8AgQ";
function fundo() {
    var w = window.innerWidth
            || document.documentElement.clientWidth
            || document.body.clientWidth;

    var h = window.innerHeight
            || document.documentElement.clientHeight
            || document.body.clientHeight;

    document.body.style.background = "url('" + url + "')";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = w + "px " + h + "px";
}
```

```html
<body onload = "fundo()"></body>
```

Comment: Yes, I really have reasons to not do it in CSS. In CSS is much easier, and I already did it. But as I'm not familiarized with javascript, I had to ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The body is full height and width anyway. You should be able to do all this with pure CSS. You can use background-size to ensure it fills the area available:

```
body {
    width: 100%; /* set just in case */
    height: 100%; /* set just in case */
    background-image: url(pathtoimage);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This will stretch the image to fill it:

```
body {
    width: 100%; /* set just in case */
    height: 100%; /* set just in case */
    background-image: url(pathtoimage);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```